# Keep user data in Firebase after Authentication

Tags: html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, web-deployment

I have been trying to make a website as a side project since its summer and I have done a lot of tutorials and research with Firebase and HTML. Now I am stuck on the design aspect. My website requires making use of authentication with email and passwords. 
For storing data about the user, what would be the base way to keep the user's data in Firebase database? Create childs named after the user's email, use the UID of the Firebase user, or are their other ways? 
TLDR What is the best/recommended way to store a user data in a way that my website can retrieve what it needs when the user logs back on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idiomatic way to store user data is in a structure:

```
users
  <uid1>
    ...
  <uid2>
    ...
```

This allows quick and efficient lookup of the signed in user.

But you may need additional data for specific use-cases. For example: if you want to ensure that each user has a username that is unique across all users, you'll typically need to add a structure that maps from username to UID:

```
usernames
  <username1>: UID
  <username2>: UID
```

For more on this see one of the many examples: https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+firebase+unique+user+name

And for other use-cases you may need yet another structure.

To learn more about NoSQL data modeling in general, I recommend reading [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/). And for Firebase specifically I recommend watching [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s).